# Auto fill in the blanks in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have 3 columns of data in Excel spreadsheet, column 1 is Business Unit, column 2 is item_ID and column 3 is Cost.  Column 2 and 3 have data in all rows but column 1 only shows business unit once then the rest are blank until the business changes.  I can just drag the business unit data and control down to the blank ones for EACH business unit, but what if I have thousands of rows and more than hundreds of business unit?  That will take me forever to do.  Is there a way to do this task faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume the data below: 
Step 1: select from cell A2 to A31 (all the data rows under Unit column)
Step 2: Click on home tab and click Find & Select.
Step 3: Select Go to Special.
Step 4: Select Blanks and hit ok.
Step 5: On the first cell, enter `=A2` (equals to the cell above the blank) then hit `ctl+enter`

[image]

Comment: This is the fastest approach, the control + enter works pretty well for this scenario.

Comment: Awesome approach, 20 years in Excel and i'm still learning :). Thanks for sharing Ming.

Comment: If you guys don't like using the mouse you can select the column by selecting A2 and hold `shift` and `down_arrow` key until end of data,  then press `alt`, `h`, `f`,`d`,`s`,`k`,`enter`,`=`,`a2`,`ctrl+enter`.

Comment: It is faster by just filtering Column `A` on all blank cells, then apply the formula, and don't forget to paste value column `A` immediately after.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that Column A is your Business Unit column, adding a temporary column next to it and replicating the first value ie `B2=A2` then on `B3`you could use the following formula:

```
=IF(A3="",B2,A3)
```

Copy it down to all your rows in Column B. After verifying its accurateness you could copy and paste as value into your column A and then delete Column B. Regards

Comment: This is a pretty cool approach but I still need to manually copy and paste the initial value of each business unit.

Comment: Actually you only have to copy the first value of the whole column. Each time you reach a row with a new business unit ie. `A(i)<>""`  it will output `A(i)` which should correspond to the name of the New Business Unit. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Warning:  Kludge

1. In Column 4 create a formula that says "If column 1 is blank, make it look like the row above it, otherwise do nothing"
2. Highlight that cell and hit Ctrl-End, which should take you to the bottom row of your spreadsheet and Shift-Click.  This should highlight the entire column.
3. Hit Ctrl-D, to fill down.  You have now copied your formula to all cells in the column.
4. Click the column 4 header and then copy (Ctrl-C).
5. Click on the column 1 header and then 'Paste Special' (Ctrl-Shift-V) and then select "Values"

Comment: How does contrl + End take me to the bottom row of my spreadsheet?  I am kinda confused about the use of it.

Comment: Ctrl-End takes you to the bottom right of your sheet.  This has been in Excel for as long as I remember.

Answer (score 0):

In D1

```
=A1
```

In D2

```
=if(A2="",D1,A2)
```

Drag down

Copy D1 to D end of data

Click on A1

Paste as values

Delete column D